# I erased my macOS Ventura using disk utilities and now I’m having trouble reinstalling macOS

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, ventura

I recently erased my Mac mini 2021 M1 chip computer using disk utilities.
Now I am trying to reinstall Mac, but no matter how long I wait, the reinstallation process does not finish. I looked at the date with the date command in the terminal to see if the time was behind. Yes, it was 3 hours behind. When I looked online, I saw that this was the same as London time, but I live in Turkey. Of course, I immediately corrected the time and tried again, but 5 minutes after correcting the time, it changes back to London time, so the reinstallation process stops while it is going well, what can I do?

Comment: What model and year of Mac is this? Are you using Internet Recovery? How (and why) did you erase the OS?

Comment: mac mini 2021, i am using the recovery mode (i guess internet recovery is the same thing), i erased it from the disk utilities, i erased it because there was way too many files and apps i downloaded

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac you could use to download and create an installer on an USB stick?

Comment: yeah, i have another macbook, but i dont know how to do that, can you send me a youtube video that explains it, i tried researching but i couldnt find any videos about it

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/101578, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos with a lot of details.

Comment: For future reference, you don't need to wipe the **OS** because of **files** you've installed. The OS and your data are on two separate disk volumes.

Comment: You also no longer need to wipe or delete partitions. Apple Silicon Macs wipe like an iPhone, with a 'Reset all Content and Settings' option. See https://support.apple.com/HT212749